# pem files to get https work in Intraweb VCL For the web

Tags: delphi, ssl, ssl-certificate, indy, intraweb

I am studying the SSLCustomIOHandler Intraweb example to figure out to make the intraweb standalone webserver work in https.

The example uses 3 `.pem` files:
basically the code that uses the files is

```
{ TIWIOHandlerClass }
procedure TIWIOHandlerClass.Init;
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := TIWAppInfo.GetAppPath;
  with SSLOptions do begin
    CipherList := 'AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH';
    SSLVersions := [sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
    CertFile := Path + 'cert.pem';
    KeyFile := Path + 'key.pem';
    RootCertFile := Path + 'root.pem';
    OnGetPassword := DoGetPassoword;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Now i don't find documentation on this thing. This [Indy documentation  page](http://www.e-iter.net/Knowledge/Indy9/007733.html) says something about `certfile` and `keyfile`.
But `Rootcertfile` and `cipherlist` are not clear.
Do you have some knowledge to share about this? Basically I'd like to have a https webserver with valid certificate ("green https" in chrome).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question has a lot to to with with SSL and public key infrastructure (PKI). You can find a lot of information on that topic on the web, but I'll try to help you get started. I don't have a version of Intraweb that supports SSL so I could not compile the sample, but hopefully this will get you somewhere.

In order to get "green https" in Chrome a few things must be fulfilled. In simple terms, this means that the certificate presented by the server must be valid in terms of expiry date, it must have a supported crypto algorithm, the hostname must be the same hostname as the requester, or client, used etc. This is far from a complete list, but you get the idea. In addition to this, the client must trust the certificate, either directly or through a hierarchy (hence the "infrastructure" in PKI). Browsers and operating systems come preloaded with authorative certificate issuers that we are assumed to trust, often called CA's (Certificate Authority). Since it is a hierarchy, there can be a path between who issued your certificate and who your browser trusts. For this reason, many clients need the server to provide a "certificate chain", that shows the path all the way to the highest CA. This is what the `Rootcertfile` is for.

If you want a server that is trusted for normal internet users, you need to get a certificate from a trusted authority. You can get simple free certificates from sites like "Let's Encrypt", but there are a few prerequisities that has to be fulfilled (for example having administrative authority of a domain), and there is also things like certificate renewal that need to be handled.

An easy way to get started is to create a self-signed certificate. This will give you the `cert.pem` and the `key.pem`. Since the certificate is "self-signed", you are your own root, so if you must have a `root.pem` I think you can use the `cert.pem` there as well. You don't have a hierarchy, and your certificate will not be trusted by anyone until you convince them otherwise.

I think that the `cipherlist` has to do with which ciphers the server supports. You can probably use the default as a start.

In order to make Chrome happy you need to import the self-signed certificate into the Trusted CA store on your client. You also need to make sure you can resolve the name(s) in the certificate. The easiest way is to add the name to the clients hostfile. This does not have to be the computers actual hostname, you can `use.whatever.you.want`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) is a good thread regarding self-signed certificates. Since you want to get started quickly, I'll cover the basics here. I guess you are on Windows since you are running Delphi.

1. Download and install OpenSSL. I used
   [Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_0g.exe](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_1_0g.exe) from [Shining Light
   Productions](https://slproweb.com/index.html).
2. Create a text file called req.cnf with the contents below. This file
   is required because modern browsers requires that the hostname is
   present in the SAN field.

   ```
   [req]
   distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
   x509_extensions = v3_req
   prompt = no
   [req_distinguished_name]
   C = NA
   ST = NA
   L = lab
   O = lab
   OU = lab
   CN = www.myintrawebserver.local    <--- Replace with your name
   [v3_req]
   keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
   extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
   subjectAltName = @alt_names
   [alt_names]
   DNS.1 = www.myintrawebserver.local <--- Replace with your name
   DNS.2 = myintrawebserver.local     <--- Optional additional name(s)
   ```
3. Go to a DOS prompt and run the following command (The backslash
   after "365" is just to make this easier to read, it won't work on
   Windows):

   ```
   C:\home>\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 \
    -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -config req.cnf
   ```

   If everything work you'll get the files `cert.pem` and `key.pem` written in 
   the current directory.

   ```
   Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
   .......................................................................
   ...................................++
   .......................................................................
   .......................................................................
   .......................................................................
   ......................................................++
   writing new private key to 'key.pem'
   -----
   ```
4. Add the hostname into the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on the client computer. Remember that you need to edit the file as Administrator.
5. Import the cert.pem into the truststore. This can be done via settings->advanced->certificates (or something like that). Add the certificate to the Trusted Root Authorities (I don't know the exact name, my computer has a non-english language).
6. Run and access your application. Hopefully your browser is happy :-)

The `key.pem` is not password protected in this example. I don't know if the 
`OnGetPassword` has something to do the key password or if it is a password 
that the user is expected to provide.

[SSLSHopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-tools.html) has some useful tools to check certificates. Try for example to paste the content of the cert.pem in the [Certificate Decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html). Sample output below.

[image: Sample output from Certificate Decoder]

The certificate is divided in two parts, so to speak. The cert.pem is the public part, and the key.pem is the part that needs to be kept secret. The public part needs to be decoded by clients in order to determine if they can trust it or not.

[How2SSL](http://how2ssl.com) also has some good information on SSL. [Here](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/) can you read more about PEM-files specifically. PEM is just one of the many file formats that help complicate the world of PKI ;-)